# Ubuntu 20.04 and conceptronic ch3hnas

Tags: networking, 20.04, nas

since my upgrade from 19.10 my desktop can't open my CH3HNAS from conceptronics.Used to work fine. CH3HNAS is found but cannot open directories. Says cannot open because of local problem.What is difference in the samba environment between 20.04 and 19.10, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved the issue yet!
Most probably it has to do with SMB/CIFS version. See if your smbclient is configured with higher version of SMB/CIFS. I believe CH3HNAS does not support SMB/CIFS connections higher than 1.0